# Is mixing the consuming/producing behaviour of the generator coroutines necessarily a bad idea?

Tags: python, generator

I am writing a data processing code using generator-based coroutines where data are continuously read from sensors or files (source), then transformed using one or more functions (filters) and finally written somewhere (sink). Here is an example using some dummy functions:

```py
def coroutine(func):
    def primed(*args, **kwargs):
        coro = func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(coro)
        return coro
    return primed

def source(name):
    for x in range(1,4):
        yield f'{name}{x}'

config = {
    'filter1': '_F1',
    'filter2': '_F2',
    'filter3': '_F3',
}

@coroutine
def filter1(**config):
    """Coroutine that consumes AND produces"""
    data = ''
    while True:
        data = yield data + config['filter1']

@coroutine
def filter2(**config):
    """Coroutine that consumes AND produces"""
    data = ''
    while True:
        data = yield data + config['filter2']

@coroutine
def filter3(**config):
    """Coroutine that consumes AND produces"""
    data = ''
    while True:
        data = yield data + config['filter3']

@coroutine
def writer(where):
    while True:
        data = yield
        print(f'writing to {where}: {data}')

def pipeline(source, transforms, sinks):
    for data in source:
        for f in transforms:
            transformed = f(**config).send(data)
        for sink in sinks:
            sink.send(transformed)


pipeline(source('data'), 
         transforms=[
             filter1,
             filter2,
             filter3,
         ], 
         sinks=[
             writer('console'),
             writer('file'),
         ])
```

It is generally not recommended to mix the consumer/producer behaviour in the coroutines (see [here](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf). However, this approach allows me to write the `pipeline` function without hard-coding the individual transform (`filter`) functions. If I was to had to stick to the "consuming" behaviour of the coroutines, this is what I was able to come up with:

```py
def coroutine(func):
    def primed(*args, **kwargs):
        coro = func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(coro)
        return coro
    return primed

def source(name, target):
    for x in range(1,4):
        target.send(f'{name}{x}')

config = {
    'filter1': '_F1',
    'filter2': '_F2',
    'filter3': '_F3',
}

@coroutine
def filter1(target, **config):
    """This coroutine only consumes"""
    while True:
        data = yield 
        target.send(data + config['filter1'])

@coroutine
def filter2(target, **config):
    """This coroutine only consumes"""
    while True:
        data = yield 
        target.send(data + config['filter2'])

@coroutine
def filter3(target, **config):
    """This coroutine only consumes"""
    while True:
        data = yield 
        target.send(data + config['filter3'])

@coroutine
def writer(where):
    while True:
        data = yield
        print(f'writing to {where}: {data}')

def pipeline():
    f3 = filter3(writer('console'), **config)
    f2 = filter2(f3, **config)        
    f1 = filter1(f2, **config)

    source('data', f1)

pipeline()
```

Now, my question: is the first implementation necessary a bad idea and if yes, what could go wrong? I like it better than the second approach, though I understand that I am mixing the generator/coroutine behaviour...

Comment: You realize that document is ~ten years old? Mr Beazley has continued to explore those concepts and adaptations with with `asyncio` - he has a number of videos on pyvideo.org

Comment: When you say you like the *first* implementation, what do you mean by that, it sounds pretty subjective. And why don't you like the second version?  Please explain by editing your question.

Comment: @wwii I know it's pretty old. To be honest, I am having difficult times developing an intuition for how `asyncio` wants me to write the code. As far as I understand there is no `send` analog in `asyncio`, so I assume you need to use some sort of `asyncio.Queue` (???).

Comment: @wwii I don't like the second because, as I mentioned, I need to hard-code the filters in the `pipeline` function (I cannot just past a list of filters like in the first version). Moreover, I need to start with the last filter, because that is the `target` for the previous filter.